# Simple OOP and PHP not working... can anyone help? :)

Tags: php, oop, constructor

My first foray into OOP with PHP - I am trying to build a query builder object that generates a query based on inputs to the object. I would imagine this is as simple as simple gets.

I expected that the line under the buildQuery function definition `$active_value=$this->getActive;` would assign 1 to the object's `active` attribute per the `__construct()` method... to no avail... what am i doing wrong to achieve the desired result i.e. buildQuery to return

```
select * from mytable where active=1
```

TIA!

```
class queryBuilder {

    function __construct(){
        $this->active=1;
    }

    public function active () {
        $this->active=1;
    }

    public function inactive () {
        $this->active=0;  
    }

    public function getActive(){
        return $this->active;
    }

    public function setActive($value){
        $this->active->$value;
    }

    public function buildQuery() {
        $active_value=$this->getActive();
        $query="select * from mytable where active=$active_value";
        return $query;
    }

}

$init=new queryBuilder();
echo $init->buildQuery();
```

Comment: So you edited this as @cwallenpoole and I posted our answers.  Is the above code now correct, as `$active_value=$this->getActive();` ?

Comment: What is it doing instead of returning correct `$query`?

Comment: Which version of php are you running?  If you are running php4 (you shouldn't be), __construct() is not available.

Answer (score 2):

### Response to edit of question

When I run this in a browser, I get `select * from mytable where active=1`. I assume that is what you need based on your question. If you want active to be quoted (which might be a typo in your original question), then you'll need to replace `$query="select * from mytable where active=$active_value";` with:

```
$query="select * from mytable where active='$active_value'";
// this will output select * from mytable where active='1'
```

If you want this to be a Boolean in MySQL, then use of 1 vs. 0 should be sufficient, but you can cast:

```
$query="select * from mytable where active=CAST($active_value as BOOL)";
// this will output select * from mytable where active=CAST(1 as BOOL)
```

### Original text

Well, first you need to use `->` instead of `=`, second you need to call the function:

```
// not: $active_value=$this=getActive;
$active_value=$this->getActive();
```

Couple of comments:

- As a general rule in OOP, methods are generally broken down to `do`, `get`, and `set`. The names are often different, but they should always be verbs. `inactive` and `active` aren't really intuitive.
- If you have methods `getActive` and `setActive` it is often a good idea to use them to modify the state of the object itself. There are exceptions for performance reasons and the like, but generally it is a good idea and it re-enforces that those methods are there. `inactive` therefore, should be `function inactive(){ $this->setActive(1);}`
- You should almost never assign a new variable to a pre-defined class. Always declare variables up front when you can (add private $active; at line 1 of the class)
- Because `$this->active` is a boolean, then it should probably be TRUE or FALSE until it is actually added to the query: `$active_value  = $this->getActive()? 1: 0;`